# Does this multivariable limit exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Does the limit  $$ \lim_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac {\cos(x+y)+\cos(x-y)-2}{x^{2}+y^{2}} $$ exist? I can't find a way to prove it.

I am having a problem because I can't find two sequences to disapprove the existence of limit by Heine characterization, but also, I failed to bound the limit using squeeze theorem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: Note that $\cos(A+B)+\cos(A-B)=2\cos(A)\cos(B)$

Comment: I've tried with that, but it doesn't help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a simpler way to solve the problem but here's a solution anyway. It's based on using the second order taylor polynomial $ 1-1/2 \;x^2$ of $\cos(x)$.

Define
$$ f(x,y) = 2\frac{ \cos(x)\cos(y)-1}{x^2 + y^2}.$$

We want to find the limit of $f$ at $(0,0)$ if it exists.

Observe that for $x$ close to $0$ and $\epsilon > 0$  we have

$$ 1 - \frac{1}{2}x^2 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1- \frac{1}{2+\epsilon}x^2$$

Note

$$ P_\epsilon(x,y) = 2\frac{(1-  \frac 1 {2+\epsilon}x^2)(1- \frac 1 {2+\epsilon} y^2)-1} {x^2 + y^2}.$$

By the above inequalities we have that for $x,y$ close to $0$ and $\epsilon > 0$ we have

$$ P_0(x,y) \leq f(x,y) \leq P_\epsilon(x,y) $$

Using the first inequality we find that

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &\geq 2 \frac{(1-\frac 1 2 x^2)(1- \frac 1 2 y^2) - 1}{x^2 + y^2} \\
       &= 2\frac{1- \frac 1 2 (x^2 + y^2) + \frac 1 4x^2y^2 - 1 }{x^2+y^2} \\
       &= 2 \frac{- \frac 1 2 (x^2 + y^2) + \frac 1 4x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \\
       &= -1 + \frac 1 2 \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}.
\end{align*}

The second inequality gives

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) &\leq 2\frac{(1-  \frac 1 {2+\epsilon}x^2)(1- \frac 1 {2+\epsilon} y^2)-1} {x^2 + y^2} \\
&= 2 \frac{ 1 - \frac 1 {2+\epsilon}(x^2+y^2) + \frac 1 {(2+\epsilon)^2}x^2y^2 -1 }{x^2 + y^2}\\
&= \frac{-2}{2 + \epsilon} + \frac{2}{(2+\epsilon)^2}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}.
\end{align*}
Knowing this we have

$$  -1 + \frac 1 2 \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}\leq f(x,y) \leq \frac{-2}{2 + \epsilon} + \frac{2}{(2+\epsilon)^2}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2 + y^2}$$
Taking the limit as $(x,y) \to 0$ and $\epsilon \to 0$ on both sides and using the squeeze theorem we find that

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0} f(x,y) = -1$$

I hope this is correct.

Comment: thank you very much